# Mouse Hover Multiple Buttons

Tags: vb.net, button

I have 5 buttons and 5 labels. I want to get value the label.text when my mouse hovers on the button and passing to it to the textbox.

**The code**

```
    Private Sub btnRoomA_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoomA.MouseHover
        notransaksiMouse = lblTransaksiRA.Text
        textbox1.text = noTransaksiMouse
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRoomB_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  btnRoomB.MouseHover
        notransaksiMouse = lblTransaksiRB.Text
        textbox1.text = noTransaksiMouse
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRoomC_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoomC.MouseHover
        notransaksiMouse = lblTransaksiRC.Text
        textbox1.text = noTransaksiMouse
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRoomD_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoomD.MouseHover
        notransaksiMouse = lblTransaksiRD.Text
        textbox1.text = noTransaksiMouse
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRoomE_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoomE.MouseHover
        notransaksiMouse = lblTransaksiRE.Text
        textbox1.text = noTransaksiMouse
    End Sub
```

The problem is I would like this all private sub to 1 private sub but I have no idea..
I try this code :

```
     Private Sub btnRoomE_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoomA.MouseHover,btnRoomB.MouseHover,btnRoomC.MouseHover,btnRoomD.MouseHover,btnRoomE.MouseHover
        notransaksiMouse = lblTransaksiRE.Text
        textbox1.text = noTransaksiMouse
    End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Does this work?

Comment: the problem the code is very long.. and i want to make 1 private sub

Comment: @yusli : better you upvote or vote as answer for the answer that help you ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub btn_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) & _
Handles btnRoomA.MouseHover, btnRoomB.MouseHover, btnRoomC.MouseHover, btnRoomD.MouseHover, btnRoomE.MouseHover
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    Select Case btn.Name
        Case "btnRoomA" : noTransaksiMouse = lblTransaksiRA.Text
        Case "btnRoomB" : noTransaksiMouse = lblTransaksiRB.Text
        Case "btnRoomC" : noTransaksiMouse = lblTransaksiRC.Text
        Case "btnRoomD" : noTransaksiMouse = lblTransaksiRD.Text
        Case "btnRoomE" : noTransaksiMouse = lblTransaksiRE.Text
    End Select

    TextBox1.Text = noTransaksiMouse
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this  ....

```
Private Sub btnRoomMouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoomA.MouseHover, btnRoomB.MouseHover, btnRoomC.MouseHover, btnRoomD.MouseHover, btnRoomE.MouseHover

    Dim s as String = CType(sender,Button).Name
    Dim lbl as Label =  CType(Me.Controls("lblTransaksiR" & s.Substring(7)), Label)
    notransaksiMouse = lbl.Text
    textbox1.text = noTransaksiMouse
End Sub
```